# Is there a way to use STOMP for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, stomp

I've search the web high and low and haven't really gotten anywhere. I'm trying to connect to a STOMP server to gain access to some [data feeds](http://www.networkrail.co.uk/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=30064782140).  I've found some [Objective C wrappers](https://github.com/juretta/objc-stomp) but the documentation is non existant and the pre ARC code generates enough alerts to make my head explode.

I'm fairly new to this area and would really appreciate a point in the right direction. Is there some iOS API that will handle this? Or does someone else know of some ARC code that will do the job?

Comment: I am also trying to access the same feeds as you! but am having the same problem. I know how to handle the json file but can't work out how to connect to the stomp server. If I find anything i will share.

Comment: @lps The documentation out there is quite bad, but I'd looks like we have to set up our own server 

https://devforums.apple.com/message/800107#800107

I've started looking at doing this with PHP, but I've got a lot to learn.

I found these websites useful
http://nrodwiki.rockshore.net/index.php/About_the_feeds#Background_reading
http://www.railforums.co.uk/showthread.php?t=67651&page=16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a library that works over sockets, the objc-stomp library is still no-ARC, but there are some forks that are ARC:

- https://github.com/lludo/objc-stomp from Ludovic Landry
- https://github.com/hstrowd/objc-stomp from Harrison Strowd

If you are looking for one that works over websockets I have done a fork of the same library that works over websockets https://github.com/nmaletm/objc-stomp (but at the moment is not ARC).

But remember that if the problem is ARC vs no-ARC, you can disable it for some files doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/2412686.

Answer (score 2):

There are a new STOMP Kit that implements ARC and blocks.
Here -> [STOMPKit](https://github.com/mobile-web-messaging/StompKit/)

It's simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

I ported StompKit to work over websocket for iOS as well. If you already have a server that can handle STOMP over websocket you can reuse it for your iOS client: [WebsocketStompKit](https://github.com/rguldener/WebsocketStompKit)